# Apache HTTP Server - 2.4.5* / Is it Possible to Use Cluster Scenario for WebLogic Server Installed On 2 Different Machines Using Apache HTTP Server?

Tags: linux, weblogic, httpserver, apache2.4, weblogic14c

There are 2 different scenarios.

**Scenario-1:**

Let's assume that WebLogic is installed on 2 different servers. Server IPs: 192.168.0.111 and 192.168.0.112. These servers are not clustered (ie each single machine). There are 10 managed servers on each of them (separately on .111 and .112).

Using Apache HTTP Server version 2.4.5*, is it possible to load balancing/redirect these 2 different single node (single machine) WebLogic Servers?

If possible, do I need a change in the little block below? Can I still use the "WebLogicCluster" option? Does it have to see a real WebLogic cluster for this, or does it work on 2 different single nodes as I mentioned in the scenario?

```
<VirtualHost *:port>
   SetHandler weblogic-handler
   WebLogicCluster WLS_IP_1:WLS_PORT_1,WLS_IP_2:WLS_PORT_2
   <Location /a_location>
     SetHandler weblogic-handler
     WebLogicCluster WLS_IP_1:WLS_PORT_1,WLS_IP_2:WLS_PORT_2
     .....
     .....
   </Location>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond...
   RewriteCond...
   RewriteRule...
   ErrorLog log_location
   CustomLog log_location
   .....
   .....
</VirtualHost>
```

**Scenario-2:**

Let's assume that WebLogic Server is installed on a single server. Server IP: 192.168.0.113. 2 managed servers are running on a single instance (single machine). In this scenario; using Apache HTTP Server version 2.4.5*, is it possible to load balancing/redirect for these 2 different managed servers?

If possible, how should I change the following block this time? Can I do this by showing 2 different ports (ports of 2 different managed servers) over the same IP?

```
<VirtualHost *:port>
   SetHandler weblogic-handler
   WebLogicCluster WLS_IP_1:WLS_PORT_1,WLS_IP_1:WLS_PORT_2
   <Location /a_location>
     SetHandler weblogic-handler
     WebLogicCluster WLS_IP_1:WLS_PORT_1,WLS_IP_1:WLS_PORT_2
     .....
     .....
   </Location>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond...
   RewriteCond...
   RewriteRule...
   ErrorLog log_location
   CustomLog log_location
   .....
   .....
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance and best regards...